# Генерация ключа PBEKeySpec

Tags: java, c#, кодировка, пароль, cryptoapi

Есть код генерации ключей на с# и java. 
Если в качестве пароля передаётся символ с кодом < 128, то программы выдают одинаковые ключи. 
Если символ с кодом > 128, то ключи разные. В c# *pass* - `byte[]`, а в java *pass* - `char[]`. 
Получается, что в c# передаём например `{251}` и всё ок, 
а в java передаётся уже два байта (из-за внутреннего представления UTF).
Подскажите пожалуйста, как в java передать в *pass* именно `{251}` без влияния кодировки?

**c#**

```
Rfc2898DeriveBytes rfc2898DeriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(pass, salt, 2);  
array[j] = rfc2898DeriveBytes.GetBytes(20);
```

**java**

```
PBEKeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(pass, salt, 2, k);  
SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");  
byte[] secretKey = factory.generateSecret(keySpec).getEncoded();
```

Answer (score 1):

PBEKeySpec корректно воспринимает только печатные символы ASCII. 
Если возможны любые символы пароля, то можно использовать :
[https://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html][1]

```
// PBKDF2 with bouncycastle in Java 
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674018/pbkdf2-with-bouncycastle-in-java/14242371#14242371
private static byte[] calculatePasswordDigest(char[] pass, byte[] salt, int iterations)
        throws PasswordException
    {
    byte[] derivedKey = null;
        try
        {
            PKCS5S2ParametersGenerator gen = new PKCS5S2ParametersGenerator();
                            gen.init(PBEParametersGenerator.PKCS5PasswordToBytes(pass), salt, iterations);
            derivedKey = ((KeyParameter)gen.generateDerivedParameters(160)).getKey();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            throw new PasswordException("PasswordDigest generation error.");
        }
        return derivedKey;
    }
```